# How can I change compiling rule less to css?

Tags: ember.js, less, ember-cli-less

I have in my less file line like this:

```
.icon-enter {
  width: 22px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;...') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

But after it would be compiled I have result:

```
.icon-enter {
  width: 22px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;...') 0 0/100% no-repeat;
}
```

So it's work fine in new Chrome. But in Android Stock Browser on Android 4.1 icon doesn't apear. If I add `background-size: 100%` in css and remove it from `background` then it will work fine in Android 4.1.

I use `Ember.js` and `ember-cli` and addon `ember-cli-less`. Can I change rule of compiling for `background-size`?

Comment: I am using a slightly older version of the Less compiler and it doesn't compress the properties automatically (what seems to be happening in your case is the `background-size` is getting added to the shorthand `background` property). Are you using any compressors or minifiers?

Comment: Less never modifies even the values you write (except some trivial cases like outputing non-transparent color values in hex). So it's not Less but some other tool in your chain performs this backsize mod (minifier? prefixer? other?).

Comment: Yes, it is minifier, and when I set `!important` for `background-size` minifier doesn't compress.

Comment: Hmm, you're better to not use hacks like `!important` (this way you're just asking for troubles in future) but read the minifier documentation and configure it to perform more friendly to the older browsers.

Comment: Please, update your question, or delete it. According to your comments it no longer makes sense. Thank you!